# Encryption at two levels (with a twist)

Tags: encryption

I have a scenario where I need to encrypt a document, then convert it to another format and then decrypt from that particular format converting into the format which would have gotten had we converted the original document without encryption.

```
In Steps - 
 Document D, Encryption E, Conversion C

 D with E gives ED
 ED converted with C gives CED
 D converted with C gives CD
 CED when decrypted should return CD
```

Does anyone know any algorithm/software/technology which help me to do this?

Thanks for the help,
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of encryption, this would only be possible if your encryption E was a stream cypher, and the conversion C was an exact byte to byte translation.  Any change to the number of bytes (for example, different end-of-line codes) would render it impossible.

In symbolic terms:

```
D XOR E => ED    (encryption)
ED XOR C => CED  (conversion ED -> CED)
D XOR C => CD    (conversion D -> CD)
CED XOR E => CD  (decryption)
```

Much simpler to separate encryption and conversion.  Only convert a decrypted version of the document.